# Nondegeneracy of dominant singular value and positivity of dominant singular vector of connected nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices, singular-values

Call a (not necessarily square) *nonnegative* matrix $M$ **connected** if there do not exist permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PMQ=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$ for some $A$ and $B$. [Perhaps this property already has a standard name.]

I'm looking for a proof of the following (assuming it's true, as I believe):

> If a matrix is (nonnegative and) connected, then
>
> 1. its dominant (greatest) singular value $s$ is not degenerate (i.e. it has unique left and right singular vectors),
> 2. the left and right singular vectors of $s$ are positive (not just nonnegative).

My guess is that this is probably relatively straightforward, or even follows directly from some standard results. However, I'm a combinatorialist with limited linear algebra, so would appreciate some help.

The context is [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091519000026) by Albert & Vatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can check (details on this to be given later) that your condition on $M$ implies that the symmetric nonnegative matrix $MM^T$ is not of the form $P^T\begin{pmatrix} N_1&0\\ 0&N_2\end{pmatrix}P$ for any permutation matrix $P$. So, the matrix $MM^T$ is primitive: it is non-negative and, for some natural number $m$, all  entries of the $m$th power of $MM^T$ are $>0$.

So, your desired result for $MM^T$ follows by the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices). Similarly, for the matrix $M^T M$.

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to seeing the details.

Comment: @DavidBevan : I will try to do this today or tomorrow.

Comment: I've added a combinatorial proof below that connected $M$ implies $MM^T$ and $M^TM$ are irrreducible. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $M$ to be the weighted biadjacency matrix of a bipartite graph $G$. If $M$ is connected then so is $G$. (This was the motivation for the terminology.)

$MM^T$ and $M^TM$ are then symmetric weighted adjacency matrices of the [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection) $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $G$ onto its two vertex sets (in which nodes are adjacent if they share a neighbour in $G$). If $G$ is connected, then so are $G_1$ and $G_2$. Thus $MM^T$ and $M^TM$ are both irreducible.